# how to register NodaTime.ZonedClock with Autofac

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject, nodatime

It is possible to register `NodaTime.SystemClock` like this: `builder.Register(_ => SystemClock.Instance).As<IClock>().SingleInstance();`, according to Pac0's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645321/how-do-i-configure-ninject-to-inject-the-nodatime-iclock#comment93343249_33645623).

How do I do the same for `NodaTime.ZonedClock`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ZonedClock` doesn't seem to have any singleton accessor like `SystemClock` does, so you have to call it's constructor. Using the same approach you used for `SystemClock`, it would look something like this:

```cs
builder
    .Register(_ => new ZonedClock(SystemClock.Instance, DateTimeZone.Utc, CalendarSystem.Gregorian))
    .As<IClock>()
    .SingleInstance();
```

You can adapt the parameters as you see fit (I added `DateTimeZone.Utc` and `CalendarSystem.Gregorian` as examples).

Keep in mind that, since both implement the same interface (`IClock`) you can't register both at the same time without using keyed registrations or something similar. If you just want to use the `ZonedClock` however, this should not be a problem.